# More precision in numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following simple function to evaluate.

```
def f0(wt):
    term1 = (1 + np.cos(wt)**2) * (1 / 3 - 2 / (wt)**2)
    term2 = np.sin(wt)**2
    term3 = 4 / (wt)**3 * np.cos(wt) * np.sin(wt)
    return 0.5 * (term1 + term2 + term3)
```

For small values of `wt` (order of `1e-4` and below), I seem to have numerical problems in the evaluation of the function. Indeed, the `term1` and `term3` have very large and almost opposite values, but `term2` is very small.

I think I improved things slightly by splitting the sum of the 3 terms into two parts, as showed here

```
def f1(wt):
    # Split the calculation to have more stability hopefully
    term1 = (1 + np.cos(wt)**2) * (1 / 3 - 2 / (wt)**2)
    term2 = np.sin(wt)**2
    term3 = 4 / (wt)**3 * np.cos(wt) * np.sin(wt)
    partial = term1 + term3
    return 0.5 * (partial + term2)
```

However, for very small but positive values of `wt`, I think there are still numerical problems. I expect this function to be smooth for any positive value of `wt`, but, as you can see from the plot attached, at values below `1e-3`, there are wild artifacts.

[image]

**My question is:** how can I improve the numerical precision of Numpy, if I am already using the data type `float64`?

**Note:** I am on a Windows 10 machine with 64 bits. I have read on other Stack Overflow threads that the class `np.float128` is not available.

#### Full code snippet

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wt = np.logspace(-6, 1, 1000)

def f0(wt):
    term1 = (1 + np.cos(wt)**2) * (1 / 3 - 2 / (wt)**2)
    term2 = np.sin(wt)**2
    term3 = 4 / (wt)**3 * np.cos(wt) * np.sin(wt)
    return 0.5 * (term1 + term2 + term3)

def f1(wt):
     # Split the calculation to have more stability hopefully
     term1 = (1 + np.cos(wt)**2) * (1 / 3 - 2 / (wt)**2)
     term2 = np.sin(wt)**2
     term3 = 4 / (wt)**3 * np.cos(wt) * np.sin(wt)
     partial = term1 + term3
     return 0.5 * (partial + term2)

plt.figure()
plt.loglog(wt, f0(wt), label='f0')
plt.loglog(wt, f1(wt), label='f1')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('wt')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think the question is not that of improving the precision of Numpy (which ultimately depends on the precision of your machine and underlying math routines as well), but instead focusing on the implementation of this function, which may need annoying special cases e.g. for small values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation) and it must not be solved using higher precision as doing so will generally postpone the actual problem. The root of the problem which is a *numerical instability* must be solved by **reformulating the mathematical expression**.
Note that `f1` is a bit better than `f0` but the cancellation issue lies in `term1 + term3`.

By transforming the expression simple development/factorization operations and using trigonometric identities one can get the following function:

```py
def f2(wt):
     sw = np.sin(wt)
     sw2 = np.sin(2*wt)
     return (sw/wt)**2 + 1/3 + (sw2 / wt - 2) / wt**2 + sw**2 / 3
```

This function is a bit more accurate but still contains a cancellation causing the same issue. This happens because of the expression `E = (sw2 / wt - 2) / wt**2` which is the root of the problem. Indeed, `np.sin(2*wt)` tends towards 2 when `wt` is near 0. Thus `sw2 / wt - 2` is close to 0 and the expression `E` is numerically unstable because of a close-to-zero value divided by another close-to-zero value. If one can *reformulate analytically* `E` to remove the *singularity*, then the resulting expression will likely be *numerically stable*. For more information you can look at the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) and [how to compute an approximation](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Sinc_function) of this function (also available in Numpy).

One simple way to solve this is to use numerical tools like **Taylor series**. Taylor series can approximate the expression of `E` **close to zero** accurately (because of its derivatives). Actually, one can use Taylor series to compute the whole expression and not only `E`. However, using Taylor series for values close to 1 give inaccurate results. In fact, the accuracy of the method drops very quickly above 1. One solution is to **only use the Taylor series for small values**.

Here is the resulting implementation:

```py
def f3(wt):
     sw = np.sin(wt)
     sw2 = np.sin(2*wt)
     reference = (sw/wt)**2 + 1/3 + (sw2 / wt - 2) / wt**2 + sw**2 / 3
     # O(13) Taylor series computation used only for near-zero values
     taylor = (  (  4. /        15.) * wt**2
               - ( 29. /       315.) * wt**4
               + ( 37. /      2835.) * wt**6
               - (151. /    155925.) * wt**8
               + (268. /   6081075.) * wt**10
               - (866. / 638512875.) * wt**12)
     # Select the best implementation
     return np.where(np.logical_and(wt >= -0.2, wt <= 0.2), taylor, reference)
```

This implementation appear to be very accurate in practice (>=12 digits of precision) while being still relatively fast. Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about you replace the sin and cosin with the first few terms of their Taylor series. Then sympy is able to give you a simple result that is hopefully better suited numerically.

First I slightly change your function so it gives me a `sympy` expression.

```
from sympy import *
t = symbols('t')

def f0(wt):
    term1 = (1 + sympy.cos(wt)**2) * (sympy.Rational(1,3) - 2 / (wt)**2)
    term2 = sympy.sin(wt)**2
    term3 = 4 / (wt)**3 * sympy.cos(wt) * sympy.sin(wt)
    return sympy.Rational(1,2)*(term1 + term2 + term3)
expr = f0(t)
expr
```

[image: sympyify function]

Now I replace sin and cos with their taylor polynomials.

```
def taylor(f, n):
    return sum(t**i/factorial(i) * f(t).diff(t, i).subs(t,0) for i in range(n))

tsin = taylor(sin, 7)
tcos = taylor(cos, 7)

expr2 = simplify(expr.subs(sin(t),tsin).subs(cos(t),tcos))
f1 = lambdify(t, expr2, 'numpy')
expr2
```

[image: polynomial version]

And finally I plot it using exactly your code. Notice that I am using `sympys` option to make a `numpy` `ufunc`.

```
wt = np.logspace(-6, 1, 1000)
plt.figure()
plt.loglog(wt, f0(wt), label='f0')
plt.loglog(wt, f1(wt), label='f1')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('wt')
plt.show()
```

[image: result plot]

Obviously this function is only good around zero and for values between 1 and 10 you should take the original function. But in case you need convincing and don't care that the function with replaced taylor polynomial looks nice you can crank the degree up to 25 making it visually agree with your function at least up until 10.

[image]

And you can combine the functions so it calculates the values around zero with my function and the other with yours like this.

```
def f2(wt):
    cond = np.abs(wt) > 1/10
    return np.piecewise(wt, [cond, ~cond], [f0,f1])
```